# object not sort based on the value in JavaScript (having key and value number)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sorting

Javascript expected object result not getting when sorting on value numbers( and both key and value are also numbers)

```
let team_id_Point = {
  26: 15,
  32: 1,
  127: 21,
};

function sortObjectbyValue(obj = {}, asc = true) {
  const ret = {};
  Object.keys(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => obj[asc ? a : b] - obj[asc ? b : a])
    .forEach((s) => (ret[s] = obj[s]));
  return JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(sortObjectbyValue(team_id_Point, false));
```

**result from above:**

```
{"26":15,"32":1,"127":21}
```

**required output:**

```
{"127":21,"26":15,"32":1}
```

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although JavaScript object properties [have an order now](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys), **relying on their order is an antipattern**.

**If you need order, use an array.**

> required output

You **cannot** get the required output with a JavaScript object, because:

- Those property names are array index names, and so the object's "order" puts them in order *numerically*.
- `JSON.stringify` follows the property order of the object.

Also note that [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (as distinct from JavaScript) considers objects *"...an **unordered** set of name/value pairs..."* So to JSON, `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` are exactly equivalent.

You could use a `Map`, but then the JSON representation wouldn't be what you're expecting.

Or you could build the JSON manually (ignoring that JSON doesn't consider objets to have any order), using `JSON.stringify` for the values but outputting the `{`, property names, and `}` yourself.

But really, if you need order, use an array.

Here's an example using an array of arrays:

```js
let team_id_Point = [
    [26, 15],
    [32, 1],
    [127, 21],
];

function sortTeamIdPoint(data = [], asc = true) {
  const result = [...data];
  const sign = asc ? 1 : -1;
  result.sort((a, b) => (a[0] - b[0]) * sign);
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}

console.log(sortTeamIdPoint(team_id_Point, false));
```

Or an array of objects:

```js
let team_id_Point = [
    {id: 26, points: 15},
    {id: 32, points: 1},
    {id: 127, points: 21},
];

function sortTeamIdPoint(data = [], asc = true) {
  const result = [...data];
  const sign = asc ? 1 : -1;
  result.sort((a, b) => (a.id - b.id) * sign);
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}

console.log(sortTeamIdPoint(team_id_Point, false));
```

Comment: It means I should have to go with an array when doing sorting objects, whether it's a number key or a string key. am I right?

Comment: @Ammar - If you want order, yes, use an array. I've added an example to the end of **one** way you might do it.